# Access props in an ES7 decorator

Tags: reactjs, decorator, redux, redux-form

I'm working on asynchronously validating my redux-form. But [the example](http://redux-form.com/5.2.5/#/examples/asynchronous-blur-validation?_k=3re4iz) doesn't really show how to use redux state, to send off an action and get the result from the state. So how can I access the props from @connect in the reduxForm decorator to achieve this?

```
@connect(
    state => (...)
    dispatch => ({
        actions: auth
    })
)
@reduxForm({
    form: 'auth.signup',
    fields,
    (values, dispatch) => ({
        // dispatch validation action here
    })
})
```

Also, putting the function directly in the decorator throws up a syntax error but the logic has to be within there to have access to the props, right?

Comment: There are no decorators in `ES7` (if you mean ES2016 by that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question wasn't really about where to put the `map*ToProps` functions, I was just blind to the fact that redux-form gives you a `dispatch` parameter which allows you to bind the action creator again purely for the use of running actions for validation.

It also requires moving the function out of the decorator into a constant just like the example linked in the question.

Here's a full example for anybody interested:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import * as auth from 'actions/auth';

const fields = [
    'username',
    'password'
];

const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(values.username) {
            let authActions = bindActionCreators(auth, dispatch);
            authActions.checkUsernameValid(values.username);
            resolve();
        }
    });
};

@reduxForm(
    {
        form: 'auth.login',
        fields,
        asyncValidate,
        asyncBlurFields: [ 'username' ]
    },
    state => ({
        usernameValid: state.auth.usernameValid,
        usernameValidError: state.auth.usernameValidError
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        authActions: bindActionCreators(auth, dispatch)
    })
)
export default class Login extends Component {
    // Component here which has access to authActions
    // if the form successfully submits.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to `connect` again. Redux-form allow you to pass `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` as the second and third parameter. So you just need,

```
@reduxForm({
  form: 'auth.signup',
  fields,
  (values, dispatch) => ({
      // dispatch validation action here
  })
}, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps).
```

`mapStateToProsp` and `mapDispatchToProps` both take in `props` of the wrapped component as the second parameter.

Comment: Note: You _will_ need to connect() again in redux-form v6.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to both `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` is an object representing the props passed to the component.

The convention is to call this parameter `ownProps`:

```
@connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ...,
    (dispatch, ownProps) => ...
)
```

The redux-form [documentation](http://redux-form.com/5.2.5/#/api/reduxForm?_k=ap3s6b) states that its `map*ToProps` functions should be the same.